# $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. How many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 3$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

> $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
>
> How many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $f$ is onto?
>
> $5!$

is this correct?

> How many functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 3$?
>
> $f(1)=1, f(1)=2, f(1)=3, f(1)=4, f(1)=5$?

I don't know what to do...

> How many onto functions $f : A \to A$ so that $(f\circ f)(1) = 3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first answer is correct. As for the second question, consider the following process of constructing a suitable function:

$f(1)$ has to be something.  If $f(1)$ is $1$, then $f(f(1))=1$, which is disallowed.  So, set $f(1)=a$, where $a$ is some number in this set which isn't $1$.

Our constraint is that $f(f(1))=3$.  That is, $f(a)$ has to be $3$.  So, set $f(a)=3$.  We are now sure that our function, however we proceed to construct the rest of it, will satisfy the constraint $f(f(1)) = 3$.  Proceed to extend the function to all other numbers in this set.  Note that any function satisfying the constraint may be constructed in this fashion.

Now, we ask the question: how many ways are there to proceed through this process?

In our first step, setting $f(1) = a$, we have four choices of $a$.  Having chosen an $a$, we have no choice but to set $f(a) = 3$.  We have $3$ more distinct elements $t\in A$ whose value $f(t)$ must be chosen from a set of the $5$ possible options in $A$.

Thus, there are $4\times 5 \times 5 \times 5 = 500$ possibilities.

---

All right, apparently this process is confusing, so let's build an example function.

First, we need to choose some $a \neq 1$.  Let's say $a = 4$.  Now, we have $f(1) = 4$, and $f(4) = 3$.

With that settled, we have to figure out what $f(2),f(3),$ and $f(5)$ are.  Let's say $f(2) = 1$, $f(3) = 3$, and $f(5) = 4$.  We now have a suitable function.  We could have picked any of $5$ values for each of $f(2),f(3)$ and $f(5)$.

Comment: I don't understand this part "We have 3 more distinct elements t∈A whose value f(t) must be chosen from a set of the 5 possible options in A"  I thought there are only 4 possibilities?

Comment: I think i m confused. can you show me some possibilities beside  f(1)=2 f(1)=3 f(1)=4 f(1)=5

Comment: No one ever said that $f$ has to be one to one or onto, so it doesn't matter what numbers were "taken up" by $f(1)$ and $f(a)$.

Comment: Yes , I understand, but then there are only 4 possibilities.  Where do you get "3 more distinct elements"?

Comment: Why only $4$?  You have $1,2,3,4$ and $5$.  $5$ possibilities.  And $3$ more distinct elements because we decided what $f(1)$ was and what $f(a)$ was for some $a = f(1)$, where $a \neq 1$. Since we found $f(t)$ for two of the $t \in A$, we have to figure out $f(t)$ for there remaining $3$ elements of $A$.

Comment: It is 4 because a≠1.? sorry,I m still confused, if you could show me other possibilities?  a=2 a=3 a=4 a=5 , these 4 possibilities are in 500, right?

Comment: Lord of the puppies: I've added a bit more of an explanation.  See if that clears anything up. _(ed ajf)_

Comment: wow, its make sense now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is correct.

**Hint :**

$f \circ f (1)=3$   means

$f(1)=2$ and  $f(2)=3$

or $f(1)=3$ and  $f(3)=3$

or $f(1)=4$ and  $f(4)=3$

or $f(1)=5$ and  $f(5)=3$